# How to code in Matlab: If an argument is empty, then default to "x" value?

Tags: matlab

I have a function with a number of arguments, but some of them are optional.

1.) If when the function is called, some are left empty, how do I code it so that it defaults to a specific value?

2.) What if of 5 arguments, 3 are optional, how can the code recognize which one to set to default? For example:

```
function [u, v] = somefxn(required, required2, optional, optional2, optional3)
```

and say when I call this function, only `optional2` is filled.

**Update:** Is there something I can use that says

```
if optional2 is empty
    return default_value
end
```

Comment: Do you mean "empty" as in `optional2=[]` or as in `somefxn(required,required2,optional,optional3)`?

Comment: @ChristianClason I suppose the second one, but aren't they the same?

Comment: They're not -- an empty variable as argument is not the same as a missing argument. Since the argument names are local to the function, Matlab has no way of telling whether the second or the third optional argument is missing. If you require arguments that are independent of their order, you need to implement key/value pairs. A rather elegant way is described [in this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2776238).

Comment: Ah. I'm rather new to programming, so I don't understand much, if any, of the information provided in the link. Is there a simpler way to let `optional2` be some default value in `somefxn(required,required2,optional,optional3)`

Comment: The answer is indeed (as usual for SO) rather compact... Unfortunately, there's no simpler way to make Matlab do something it was not designed to do. If you really(!) need to account for missing arguments, your best bet is to adapt the SO answer (you just need to replace the line `option=...` with the full(!) list of expected arguments); otherwise you should follow  Nat Wilson's edited suggestion (which is how most Matlab commands such as `gmres` work, in fact).

Comment: You can do this in a slightly more elegant way (though that's a matter of taste) using inputParser().  One example is [here](https://github.com/ketch/RK-opt/blob/master/RK-coeff-opt/rk_opt.m) (just look at the setup_params() function starting on line 178).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson - While elegance is a matter of taste, robustness is not. Your suggestion is really how optional inputs should be handled if you can't rely on their order (or validity).

Comment: The `inputParser` class is indeed the way to go. I met only two exceptions.

1) the function is called many times and therefore there is a significant overhead.
2) the validation of inputs is difficult, e.g. cross-dependency between the input parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one take:

1) In Matlab, if you use `varargin`, then you must provide all preceding optional arguments (that is, `optional` must be given as well as `optional2`). In this case (for example, if you call `somefxm(myarg, myarg2, myoptarg, myoptarg2)`, then you know based on the length of `varargin` (2) that only `optional3` needs a default applied. You can have an if statement that says something like

```
if length(varargin) == 2
    optional3 = 3;  % or whatever
end
```

You can have additional conditional statements to handle having only one optional argument (e.g. `length(varargin) == 1`) or no optional arguments (e.g. `length(varargin) == 0`).

2) *Note that with this scheme, Matlab has no clever way of knowing which function argument fits into which option, so you must keep everything in sequential order.* If you need more flexibility, you can do something sort of like keyword arguments by preceding the argument with a descriptive string, which is the way that some common functions like `plot` work. Then you either need to write logic to parse `varargin` (as in Christian Clason's comment), or you can use the `inputParser` object.

**edit**

Another (in my opinion, clunkier) way of treating an "empty" `optional2` is to test whether the provided argument is simply an empty matrix, with

```
if isempty(cell2mat(varargin(2))
    optional2 = 3; % or whatever
end
```

Then, you could call `somefxn` with an "empty" second optional argument as:

```
somefxn(myarg, myarg2, myoptarg, [], myoptarg3)
```

Then, the second optional argument will be assigned whatever you've coded into the function. If you do this, you need to make sure that *an empty matrix is not an otherwise valid argument to `somefxn`*, otherwise you'll have just overloaded the proper behaviour.

Comment: You can also use `nargin` (and `nargout`) instead of `length(varargin)` (and `length(varargout)`) if you know the number of optional arguments beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this in a way that isn't as prone to breaking when the order of the arguments changes using [`inputParser()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html), which also allows you to validate the arguments.

One example is [here](https://github.com/ketch/RK-opt/blob/master/RK-coeff-opt/rk_opt.m) (just look at the `setup_params()` function starting on line 178).  More documentation with examples is [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2012/02/13/parsing-inputs/).

Answer (score 3):

Input parameter handling in Matlab is just really annoying. This works:

```
function out = foobar(foo, bar, baz)
    if ~exist('baz', 'var') ||  isempty(baz)
        baz = 'default_value';
    end
```

This needs to be repeated for all optional input parameters. Pro: it also does not depend on the order of the parameters in the function definition. Another option are all the `nargin` hacks:

```
if nargin < 3 || isempty(baz)
    baz = 'baz';
    if nargin < 2 || isempty(bar)
        bar = 'bar';
        if nargin < 1 || isempty(foo)
             foo = 'foo';
        end
    end
 end
```

Obviously this is ugly and not very extensible; plus it is dependent on the definition order of the parameters.

The last option might be inputParser, but I have no idea how you can easily do the 'isempty' part with it. I can't find this type of input handling in the example posted by @DavidKetcheson.

**Edit**: @FedericoPoloni mentions another alternative: option structures. I think they are okay if you have many input parameters (and if you throw an error if an unknown field name is parsed to circumvent the confusion FredericoPoloni mentions). I would use something like this
:

```
function test(foobar, opts)

default_opts.foo = 'foo';
default_opts.bar = 'bar';

if nargin > 1
    opts = parse_opts(default_opts, opts);
end
```

And as a separate function:

```
function parsed_opts = parse_opts(default_opts, in_opts)

in_fields = fieldnames(in_opts);
n_in_fields = numel(in_fields);

parsed_opts = default_opts;

for i_field = 1:numel(in_fields)
    cur_field = in_fields{i_field};

    if isfield(default_opts, cur_field)
        parsed_opts.(cur_field) = in_opts.(cur_field);
    else
        error('parse_opts:input', 'Unknown field name `%s`', cur_field);
    end
end
```

Comment: +1 for the first method. By far the most readable and fastest to code/modify.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add to the list another method that is used a lot in Matlab but that I **do not** recommend, to point against it: `options` structures.

Basically, your syntax requires an additional options struct `opts`, and you check for the presence of specific fields. Example:

```
>> options.TolX=1-e-3;
>> x=fzero(fun,x0,options)
```

---

```
% in fzero.m
function x=fzero(fun,x0,options)
if not(isfield(options,'TolX'))
    tol=defaultTolerance;
else
    tol=options.TolX;
end
```

---

This is what is used in several standard Matlab methods, for instance [fzero](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html#inputarg_options) that I used for this example.

The main reason why you should not do it is that error checking is terrible: if you have a field `options.tolX` (missing capital T), things will often go silently wrong.